# django NoReverseMatch Exception in django

Tags: django

I have tried many of the solutions in this website to solve the issue but I still get the error. Here I put all the needed information:

views.py:

```
def about(request):
    return render_to_response('homepage/about.html')
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.apps.homepage.views',

 url(r'^$', 'index', name="homepage_index"),
 url(r'^about/$', 'about', name="homepage_about"),
 url(r'^contact/$', 'contact', name="homepage_contact"),
 url(r'^archive/$', 'archive', name="homepage_archive"),
)
```

global urls.py:

```
(r'^$',include('blog.apps.homepage.urls')),
```

global settings.py:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'
```

tree:

```
templates/
├── base.html
└── homepage
    ├── about.html
    ├── archive.html
    ├── contact.html
    └── index.html
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block title %}
 Index Page
{% endblock %}

{% block navi %}
<a href="{% url 'homepage_index' %}">home</a> - 
<a href="{% url 'homepage_about' %}">about</a> - 
<a href="{% url 'homepage_contact' %}">contact</a> - 
<a href="{% url 'homepage_archive' %}">archive</a>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <h3>Entries:</h3>

    {%for e in entries %}
        <div>{{e.title}} - {{e.created}}</div>
        <div>{{e.text}}</div>
        <br/>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

{%block footer %}
2012 - MyBlog
{% endblock %}
```

Error:

> Reverse for 'homepage_about' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{}' not found.

Comment: remove the `''` around `homepage_about`. it will work. `{% url homepage_index %}`

Comment: @karthikr, no, it then gives the same error for `{% url homepage_index %}`

Comment: @rowman try changing `(r'^$',include('blog.apps.homepage.urls')),` to `(r'',include('blog.apps.homepage.urls')),`

Comment: @AamirAdnan, great it works. Could you post an answer on the reason behind it.

Comment: @rowman i have posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
(r'^$', include('blog.apps.homepage.urls'))
```

to

```
(r'', include('blog.apps.homepage.urls'))
```

The reason is `$` sign (used to match end of string) which means that there should not come anything afterwards. But as you are including the urls then `$` should not be there.